# How to save the state of toggle button after the page is reloaded using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to js can you guys please help me with this problem.
How can I use local storage to save the state of the buttons even after the page is refreshed/reloaded
below is the code I'm using for toggle buttons to hide and show the columns but when the page is refreshed the hidden columns are visible again. please help

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $headings = $('.heading');

  $('.hide').on('click', e => {
    let $el = $('.col' + e.target.dataset.targetIndex).toggle();
    let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length;
    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
      <th class="heading" colspan="7">abcd</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>

      <td class="col1">col1</td>
      <td class="col2">col2</td>
      <td class="col3">col3</td>
      <td class="col4">col4</td>
      <td class="col5">col5</td>
      <td class="col6">col6</td>
      <td class="col7">col7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button class="hide" data-target-index="1">1</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="2">2</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="3">3</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="4">4</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="5">5</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="6">6</button>
<button class="hide" data-target-index="7">7</button>
```

[Fiddle link for the code](https://jsfiddle.net/xrk8yf0v/35/)

Comment: learn how to use `local storage` [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery($ => {
  let $headings = $('.heading');
  var prevData = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem('prevData')){
    var prevData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('prevData'));
    if(prevData && prevData.length>0){
    prevData.forEach((e)=>{
        if(prevData.includes(e)){
      let $el = $('.col' + e).toggle();
    let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length;
    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
      }
        
    })
    }
  }
  $('.hide').on('click', e => {
    let $el = $('.col' + e.target.dataset.targetIndex).toggle();
    if(!(prevData && prevData.length>=0)){
        prevData=[];
    }
    var prevIndex = prevData.indexOf(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);
    if(prevIndex>=0){
    prevData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    }else{
    prevData.push(e.target.dataset.targetIndex);
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem('prevData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
    let colspan = $('table tbody tr:first > td:visible').length / $headings.length;
    $headings.prop('colspan', colspan);
      
});
});
```

Comment: yes plss js fiddle link of the above code https://jsfiddle.net/xrk8yf0v/35/

Comment: no its not working...i cant even toggle the button now 

Comment: @aastha i have edited answer please check and let me know, localstorage is not working in fiddle so check

Comment: can you share me error from console @aastha

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. @JayPatel please see [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers) post

Comment: "jQuery.Deferred exception: prevRes.split is not a function", "TypeError: prevRes.split is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.&lt;anonymous&gt; (https://fiddle.jshell.net/htj53o2u/14/show/?editor_console=:274:24)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:30038)
    at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:30340)", undefined
"Script error."

Comment: @aastha i have edited again please check

Comment: @JayPatel still the same error "jQuery.Deferred exception: prevData.forEach is not a function", "TypeError: prevData.forEach is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.&lt;anonymous&gt; (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:275:14)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:30038)
    at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:30340)", undefined
"Script error."

Comment: @aastha please check

Comment: now its not giving an error and i'm able to toggle the buttons but the state of the button is not saving when page is refreshed @JayPatel

Comment: @aastha still not working?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not important to use local storage you can use Cookies for that. I wrote some functions for that:

```
export function getDocumentCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
export function setDocumentCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (document.cookie.toString().match(/ + name + =/g)) {
        document.cookie.replace(/ + name + =*; path=\//g, "");
    }
    let expires = "";
    if (days) {
        const date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

`setDocumentCookie("myToggle", state)`